# Trying to pass Bandit level 27 on OvertheWire.org. Git clone not working

Tags: git, ssh, clone, repo, bandit

I've been working my way through bandit on OverTheWire, and I'm stuck on Level 27. The instructions for this level are as follows: "There is a git repository at ssh://bandit27-git@localhost/home/bandit27-git/repo. The password for the user bandit27-git is the same as for the user bandit27.

Clone the repository and find the password for the next level."

I've created a temp directory, and I'm running the git clone command, followed by the address of the repository from the temp directory.
[image: Here's a screenshot of what is happening when I run the command.]
From what I understand, I should be asked for a password, but I'm not prompted for a password, and am given the message "permission denied (publickey). fatal: could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights, and the repository exists.

Can anyone provide insight on what I might be doing wrong?

So far I've tried changing the port that I connect to, which didn't work. I have also tried generating a ssh key, but I can't seem to find a /.ssh directory to copy it to. I'm a complete noob, so I'm probably doing something wrong there.

Comment: I have no idea what this "OverTheWire bandit" thing might be, but the first thing to do when having any trouble with git-via-ssh is to drop Git from the equation: run `ssh` directly, with options like `-Tv`, and observe ssh debug output. If ssh can't connect, Git (which just *runs* ssh) won't be able to connect via ssh. If ssh *can* connect and you can run commands, Git generally *should* "just work", although there are specific problems that can crop up here—but testing via ssh only, eliminating Git entirely, always comes first.

Comment: What about appending `.git` to your clone command? `git clone ssh://bandit27-git@localhost/home/bandit27-git/repo.git`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @torek: Thanks for your response. Over the wire is a game server built to teach basic linux and hacking skills. Bandit is the beginning level game on it. I tried your suggestion, and ran ssh bandit27-git@localhost -p2220, and got the following output: "fatal: interactive git shell is not enabled. hint: ~/git-shell-command should exist and have read and execute access."

Comment: @JoshFriedlander, thanks for responding. I tried your suggestion but got the same result as before. :(

Comment: OK, so it looks like the server's ssh-server on port 2220 inspects the incoming command but is intended to allow certain Git operations (similar to the way a `git@github.com` "login" works). Since you're going to `localhost`, presumably you can set up the required file. You'll need to make sure that your *Git* ssh command *also* uses port 2220 instead of the default port 22: you can configure this in ssh itself, or in Git using `core.sshCommand` or similar.

Comment: @torek, thanks! I guess earlier when I tried changing the port I connect to, I was using the wrong syntax. I was able to connect with the following command: git clone ssh://bandit27-git@localhost:2220/home/bandit27-git/repo. That gave me the files I needed to find the password to the next level. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

git clone ssh://bandit27-git@localhost:2220/home/bandit27-git/repo worked for me as was stated above. I also had some trouble with the syntax to set the port to 2220... (i did a -p 2220, im fairly new to this stuff so lucky someone told the right way to do it :) )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

just add the port 2220

as in

ssh://bandit27-git@localhost:2220/home/bandit27-git/repo

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the port:

git clone ssh://bandit27-git@localhost:2220/home/bandit27-git/repo

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).